# How do I create an emulator in Ecllipse Juno

Tags: android, eclipse

May be my question seems to be dumb as i'm new baby to this...

I'm trying to run an android application in 7 inch Samsung Galaxy tab(7 inch)...everything work fine but when i move on to Samsung Galaxy Tab S2(10 inch) i faced an alignment issue in my application...Getting crashed sometimes too.

Can anyone suggest what should i do to resolve it...Have to create separate layout files for 10 inch tablet????

Please also tell me how can i test my application in an Samsung Galaxy Tab S2 10 inch emulator.

Comment: I would recommend switching to android studio as eclipse is no longer supported. You can use Bluestack as emulator.

Answer (score 1):

I can really recommend using [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/)  as an Emulator. It' very fast, and only has some minor limitations as free version, like you might not be able to use Google APIs.
It also provides predefined settings for different Devices.
If you don't want to use a third Party Emu, you could of course use the [Android Studio Emulator](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator.html) too.

For the crashes: get used to use the Debugger and to using Unit Tests.

I would also recommend switching from Eclipse to [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/migrate.html), since Eclipse is no longer the supported IDE by Google. Migrating your project shouldn't be a hassle.

Without your Layout code people won't be able to help you on that part.